# Adding a class to an element to run CSS animation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, animation

I'm trying to add my CSS animation class to an element when triggered by the js code. JS:

```
 if (document.getElementById("user").value == "test"
   && document.getElementById("pass").value == "test")
    {
        alert( "Welcome back!" );
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("fail").className += "animation";
    }
```

The animation won't play when the onclick event listener is triggered. The 'if' part of the statement works correctly but the 'else' part will not run.

CSS:

```
.animation {
    animation: shake 1s;

}

@keyframes shake {


      25% { transform: translate(10px)}
      50% { transform: translate(-10px)}
      75% { transform: translate(10px)}
      100% { transform: translate(-10px)}


}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
                        <!--LOGIN-->

                    <div id="fail">

                        <p>My Account</p>

                        <p id="note">Username must be between 6 and 10 characters. <br/>Password must be at least 5 characters contain at least one letter and number.</p>
                        <form id="login">

                            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="user"/>

                            <br/>

                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass"/>

                            <br/>

                            <input onclick="login()" type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, do u already have other classes in the element ***fail***

Comment: No, fail is only used once. It's the id I have in a div.

Comment: Can u show ur div having id ***fail***. Plz paste exactly what u have in ur code.

Comment: Just updated the code

Comment: @گوروسینی Just updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the submit input attribute type = button.

submit will initiate a request and refresh the page, the animation will not be seen.

Answer (score 0):

U might be putting your script in your login function which submit the form as soon as clicked and reload the page. Try this script...

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (
    document.getElementById("user").value == "test" &&
    document.getElementById("pass").value == "test"
  ) {
    alert("Welcome back!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("fail").className += "animation";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `load` and `click` events before to add the CSS class.

Try it with the next code and provide feedback please.

```
<script>
  addEventListener("load", eventClick);

  function eventClick() {
    document.getElementById("user").addEventListener("click", addClass);
  };

  function addClass() {
    var e = document.getElementById("user");
    e.classList.add("animation");
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ppcoding's solution does work, but in a lot of cases with forms, you *do want* them to submit—even if you aren't using the built in GET or POST methods for submissions.

Especially for collaboration with other developers, using a `<button>` with `type="submit"` is better, so that it's clear that it submits the information.

When doing some kind of custom submission function, you should use `preventDefault()` on the event:

```
function login(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // ... continued code
}
```

Also, it's not recommended to use event listeners in the HTML. It's better to put it in your JavaScript:

```
<!-- HTML Before -->
<form>
  // other inputs
  <input onclick="login()" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<!-- HTML After -->
<form id="login">
  // other inputs
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
// JavaScript
const loginForm = document.querySelectorAll('#login')

loginForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // ... login
})
```

I know there was already a solution, but for those that are looking to make their code more professional, this is how you do it.